# Components composition - validation issue

Tags: angular, validation

I am making simple forms and wanted to not repeat the same components again and again. So I created a few components which groups other inputs together.

Here is the example project:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-5whzeh

As you can see: Input remains invalid, but form as a whole is valid. What should I add to make it work?

EDIT:

As you can see in demo: Input is invalid when it not contain any text (is empty). Thats okay. But look at the form validity. It is always valid ignoring input validity completely.

I thought it will be like this:

Input: valid, Form: valid

Input: invalid, Form: invalid

Comment: Put a [mcve] *in the question*.

Comment: Please add the most relevant code that you've included in the demo here for posterity.

Comment: Edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error in the console of the stackblitz demo.

> ERROR
>   Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl. Did you forget to add matInput to the native input or textarea element?

To fix this just add `matInput` anywhere in attributes. Like so:

```
<mat-form-field>
      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="value" name="input" #input="ngModel" name="test" 
          required placeholder="im invalid">
</mat-form-field>
```

This should get rid of the error, and the output of the form validity will show.

[Updated Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-extvto?file=app/my-component.html)

Comment: See my updated question. I want the form to be invalid when input is invalid.

Comment: @Krzysztof you need to pass a reference to the input. For something like that id recommend using a reactive form and then you could just pass a reference of the form control.